# Navigate up to last shown fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, up-button

I've implemented a NavigationDrawer within the `MainActivity` which containts two Fragment. The second Fragment contains a `ListView` that opens a new Activity (onItemClick) that shows the according detailed data. (I guess that's pretty much the master/detail flow).

When I use the up button to navigate back I got shown the first fragment and not the second fragment with the ListView.

Any ideas how to solve that problem?

Comment: have you overriden onBackPressed ?

Comment: Not yet, but I see it's for the case the user pressed the BACK key, isn't it? I'm looking for a solution to get to the last fragment when the user pressed UP in the ActionBar.

Comment: then I believe you have everything you need here: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: I already implemented `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); return true;` within `optionsItemSelected`. It just takes the user back to MainActivity - first fragment.

Comment: well, then make method in MainActivity for example setFragment(int whichFragment) ... and set fragment you want in it, you should already have code that do that
and than call that method from onback

Comment: some feedback would be nice :) if you still cant figure this out, provide some codez and I will help you

Comment: I see that your solution will work. Thank you. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as solved. Nevertheless I'm wondering if a new Activity is the right way to implement the master/detail flow. Wouldn't be the usage of another fragment for the details more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make method in MainActivity for example `setFragment(int whichFragment);` 
and set fragment you want in it, you should already have code that do that and than call that method in `onBackPressed()` method.

For your question about another fragment, well it depends on how your master/detail flow is suppose to work, it is not a problem to use another activity if you dont need left menu any more, but if you do need left menu then use another fragment.

Best regards